# How to expand a df by a list of different dict?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

My problem is linked to my other question here ([How to expand a df by different dict as columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57686812/how-to-expand-a-df-by-different-dict-as-columns)):

I have a df with A LIST (!) of different dicts as entries in a column, in my case column "information". I would like to expand the df by all possible dict.keys() within that list, something like that:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]),
                   'name': pd.Series(['banana',
                                      'apple',
                                      'orange',
                                      'strawberry' ,
                                      'toast']),
                   'information': pd.Series([[{'shape':'curve','color':'yellow'}],
                                             [{'color':'red'},{'color':'green'}],
                                             [{'shape':'round'}],
                                             [{'amount':500}],
                                             np.nan]),
                   'cost': pd.Series([1,2,2,10,4])})

   id        name                              information  cost
0   1      banana  [{'shape': 'curve', 'color': 'yellow'}]     1
1   2       apple   [{'color': 'red'}, {'color': 'green'}]     2
2   3      orange                     [{'shape': 'round'}]     2
3   4  strawberry                        [{'amount': 500}]    10
4   5       toast                                      NaN     4
```

Should look like this:

```py
   id        name  shape   color  amount  cost
0   1      banana  curve  yellow     NaN     1
1   2       apple    NaN     red     NaN     2
2   2       apple    NaN   green     NaN     2
3   3      orange  round     NaN     NaN     2
4   4  strawberry    NaN     NaN   500.0    10
5   5       toast    NaN     NaN     NaN     4
```

(Note the additional row at index 2)

Answer (score 1):

We can using `explode` start from pandas 0.25.0

```
df1=df.explode('information').reset_index(drop=True)
df1=pd.concat([df1,pd.DataFrame(df1.information.dropna().tolist())],axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer WeNYoBen, but i found something strange:

If you consider the following df:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]),
                   'name': pd.Series(['banana',
                                      'apple',
                                      'orange',
                                      'strawberry' ,
                                      'toast']),
                   'information': pd.Series([[{'shape':'curve','color':'yellow'}],
                                             [{'color':'red'},{'color':'green'}],
                                             np.nan,
                                             [{'shape':'round'}],
                                             [{'amount':500}]]),
                   'cost': pd.Series([1,2,2,10,4])})

   id        name                              information  cost
0   1      banana  [{'shape': 'curve', 'color': 'yellow'}]     1
1   2       apple   [{'color': 'red'}, {'color': 'green'}]     2
2   3      orange                                      NaN     2
3   4  strawberry                     [{'shape': 'round'}]    10
4   5       toast                        [{'amount': 500}]     4
```

(we shifted the np.nan to "orange")

You will get the following result:

```py
   id        name  cost  shape   color  amount
0   1      banana     1  curve  yellow     NaN
1   2       apple     2    NaN     red     NaN
2   2       apple     2    NaN   green     NaN
3   3      orange     2  round     NaN     NaN
4   4  strawberry    10    NaN     NaN   500.0
5   5       toast     4    NaN     NaN     NaN
```

Your answer skips the np.nan of "orange" and fills "toast" with np.nan.

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround:

```py
a = {'shape':np.nan}
df['information'] = df['information'].apply(lambda d: d if isinstance(d, list) else [a])

   id        name                              information  cost
0   1      banana  [{'shape': 'curve', 'color': 'yellow'}]     1
1   2       apple   [{'color': 'red'}, {'color': 'green'}]     2
2   3      orange                         [{'shape': nan}]     2
3   4  strawberry                     [{'shape': 'round'}]    10
4   5       toast                        [{'amount': 500}]     4

df1=df.explode('information').reset_index(drop=True)
df1=pd.concat([df1,pd.DataFrame(df1.information.dropna().tolist())],axis=1)
df1 = df1.drop('information',True)

   id        name  cost  shape   color  amount
0   1      banana     1  curve  yellow     NaN
1   2       apple     2    NaN     red     NaN
2   2       apple     2    NaN   green     NaN
3   3      orange     2    NaN     NaN     NaN
4   4  strawberry    10  round     NaN     NaN
5   5       toast     4    NaN     NaN   500.0
```